# How to solve protocol error in Mutal TLS authentication

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp, grpc-java

Im using mutual TLS authentication between my android client and python server, the handshake is going ok, but i get the error `UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL` on my python server.
my server **is not web based** and when i tried connecting to it via a python client it worked well.
heres my android client:

```java
try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 private static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFFF];
        for (int len = is.read(buffer); len != -1; len = is.read(buffer)) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return os.toByteArray();
    }

    // build a key store from a set of raw certificates
    private static KeyStore createKeyStore(Resources resources, int certsId, boolean ca) {
        KeyStore ks = null;
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            if (ca) {
                ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                ks.load(null, null);
                InputStream certIS = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.server);
                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(certIS);
                ks.setCertificateEntry("ca", cert);
            } else {
                ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
                ks.load(null, null);
                InputStream certIS = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.client);
                Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(certIS);
                InputStream privateKeyIS = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.key);
                byte[] privateKeyBytes = getBytesFromInputStream(privateKeyIS);
                KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKeyBytes)));
                Certificate[] certChain = new Certificate[1];
                certChain[0] = cert;
                ks.setKeyEntry("client", privateKey, null, certChain);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return ks;
    }

    public static ManagedChannel build(String host, int port, Resources resources,
                                       @Nullable String serverHostOverride) {
        KeyStore ca = createKeyStore(resources, R.array.certs, true);
        KeyStore client = createKeyStore(resources, R.array.certs, false);
        OkHttpChannelBuilder channelBuilder =
                OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port);
        if (serverHostOverride != null) {
            // Force the hostname to match the cert the server uses.
            channelBuilder.overrideAuthority(serverHostOverride);
        }
        try {
            channelBuilder.connectionSpec(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
            channelBuilder.negotiationType(io.grpc.okhttp.NegotiationType.TLS);
            channelBuilder.useTransportSecurity();
            channelBuilder.sslSocketFactory(getSslSocketFactory(ca, client));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return channelBuilder.build();
    }

    private static SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory(KeyStore ca, KeyStore client)
            throws Exception {
        KeyManagerFactory kmf =
                KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        String password = "";
        kmf.init(client, password.toCharArray());

        // initialize trust manager factor from certs keystore
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ca);

        // initialize SSL context from trust manager factory
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

        // return socket factory from the SSL context
        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

my certificates are in .crt format and my key is in PKCS#8.
I believe that the problem is me not using TLS v1.2 , but whenver i change the SSLContext instance to "TLSv1.2" it doesnt do anything, and when i change my `channelBuilder.connectionSpec(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);`
to something else, the handshake doesn't go through and my server throws `LAST OCTET INVALID` and `FIRST OCTET INVALID`

Comment: Could you provide the full log of the request while you start your application with the following VM argumenets: `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake`

Comment: if you still need help, i can see a likely  error in your code 'certIS'